# Why does the firebug console keep saying "undefined" when I enter a json object?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Here is a short transcript from my firebug console:

```
>>> var a = {"name": "bob"};
>>> a
undefined name=bob
>>> a.name
"bob"
>>> b = 10
10
>>> b
10
```

Why does firebug print "undefined"? Why on a and not b?

Inquiring minds want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version are you using? To me it prints

```
>>> var a = {"name":"bob"};
>>> a
{ name=bob }
```

I'm using Firebug 1.4.5/Firefox 3.5.5.

Comment: 1.4.0b4 on Linux. I guess its time to upgrade!

Comment: yup, that was it, I guess it was a bug.

Answer (score 1):

After you've created `var a = {"name": "bob"};` in the Console, you can always switch over to Script -> Watch and then enter your `a` there to get a nice representation of your object/variable/element/whatever.

What's odd is that when I do exactly what you did, I don't see `Undefined name=bob`, I see `Object name=bob` (which is probably what you were expecting, and hence your question).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you might be using a variable that is used in the json library. Try choosing a variable that isn't very common.